# Unknown validator: 'RedirectUriValidator' during Rails deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, doorkeeper

We had a server problem, so a replacement VM was fired up many of the items copied over to the new VM (which is Ubuntu 12.04).

I'm running cap deploy to the server and everything goes well until the rake db:migrate step at which point I get:

** [out :: 63.247.75.161] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] Unknown validator: 'RedirectUriValidator'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.14/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:96:in `rescue in block in validates'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.14/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:93:in`block in validates'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.14/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in `each'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.14/lib/active_model/validations/validates.rb:90:in`validates'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/doorkeeper-0.6.7/lib/doorkeeper/models/application.rb:10:in `<class:Application>'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/doorkeeper-0.6.7/lib/doorkeeper/models/application.rb:2:in`'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/doorkeeper-0.6.7/lib/doorkeeper/models/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`load_dependency'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/doorkeeper-0.6.7/lib/doorkeeper/config.rb:24:in`enable_orm'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/doorkeeper-0.6.7/lib/doorkeeper/config.rb:10:in `configure'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/releases/20131011015404/config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb:2:in`'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`block in load'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`load'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in`each'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] 
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/releases/20131011015404/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`load_dependency'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in`require_environment!'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] /var/www/test/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/application.rb:305:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
 ** [out :: 63.247.75.161] (See full trace by running task with --trace)

I've tried several flavors of doorkeeper, and a both ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3.

I cannot figure out why this is broken all of a sudden.  I've done a lot of application changes since the last deploy, but nothing around the doorkeeper implementation.

Comment: I had thought this was being caused by the doorkeeper initializer running before I could get the database structure updated.  However, I now have everything current, and yet I still hit the error.

Comment: This definitely arises when I add "require 'doorkeeper'" at the top of the doorkeeper.rb initializer.  I've added this in an attempt to fix this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418527/uninitialized-constant-doorkeeper-on-ubuntu.

Comment: In my case, resolved with me with upgrading the gem doorkeeper-mongodb

`bundle update doorkeeper-mongodb`